# export http_proxy command equivalent

Tags: macos, terminal, proxy

I am trying to proxy my MacOS terminal and export http_proxy doesn't seem to do the job.

What are the equivalent of export http_proxy command?

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain what you were trying to do in your terminal? Which commands were used? What parameters did you pass to them?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.